# alter simple string using jquery

Tags: jquery

Just trying to do real simple thing - as a variable I get a string which I want to alter. 
html

```
<div id="body" class="abc cde fgh xxx-23">text</div>
```

jquery

```
if ($("#body").hasClass("cde")) {
    var clasa = $('#body').attr('class').match(/\bxxx-.+?\b/);
    var arr = clasa.replace('xxx', '');
    alert(arr);
}
```

Alert gives me nothing. I only want to show the number. What I am doing wrong? .attr should return string no? Thank you for help.

Comment: `var arr = clasa[0].replace('xxx', '');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code.

```
if ($("#body").hasClass("cde")) {
    var clasa = $('#body').attr('class').match(/\bxxx-.+?\b/);
    var arr = clasa[0].replace('xxx', '');
    alert(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex group like

```js
if ($("#body").hasClass("cde")) {
    var value = $('#body').attr('class').match(/\bxxx-(\d+)\b/)[1];
    alert(value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="body" class="abc cde fgh xxx-23">text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You made mistake in your match()

if you want to read only numbers from that String then use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var clasa = $('#body').attr('class').match(/[0-9]+$/);
alert(clasa);
var arr = clasa.replace('xxx', '');
alert(arr);
```

});

and if you want to read whole number xxx-23 then use following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var clasa = $('#body').attr('class').match(/xxx-[0-9]+$/);
alert(clasa);
var arr = clasa.replace('xxx', '');
alert(arr);
```

});